# Changing Raspberry PI ip address Via Python

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I am making a user application that we will deploy on machines. The end user will have little linux experience so I wanted in our GUI to give them an option to set the IP. It seems to take the IP but loses it over reboot. I am using netifaces to read the IP and system commands to set it. Inside python or the linux cmd line I am seeing the same result. After an change ifconfig shows the change. After a reboot it reverts back. Do I need to modify the eth config file?

```
import netifaces as ni
from os import system

def getIPs():
    #Grab Current IP Address
    eth0 = ni.ifaddresses('eth0')[2][0]['addr']
    wlan0 = ni.ifaddresses('wlan0')[2][0]['addr']
    return eth0, wlan0

def setEth0(ipAddress):
    if ipAddress != "":
        system('sudo ifconfig eth0 down')
        system(f'sudo ifconfig eth0 {ipAddress}')
        system('sudo ifconfig eth0 up')

def setWlan0(ipAddress):
    if ipAddress != "":
        system('sudo ifconfig wlan0 down')
        system(f'sudo ifconfig wlan0 {ipAddress}')
        system('sudo ifconfig wlan0 up')
```

Comment: You may have better luck on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I changed the process to actually modify the following file instead of sending the system commands.

```
/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0
```